# Consulta SQL en Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Como puedo pasar la siguiente consulta en Laravel 5.4

```
SELECT CONCAT( 
  TRIM(SUBSTRING(NombreCliente,1,1)),  
  TRIM(SUBSTRING(NombreCliente, locate( ' ',NombreCliente), 2) ) 
)INICIALES FROM `cliente`
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba simplemente poniendo tu selección personalizada dentro del `select` de *Query Builder*:

```
  $result = DB::table('cliente')
            ->selectRaw("CONCAT( TRIM(SUBSTRING( NombreCliente,1,1) ), TRIM(SUBSTRING( NombreCliente, locate( ' ',NombreCliente), 2) ) ) INICIALES")
            ->get();
```

---

Para saber más sobre `Query Builder` aquí el [enlace de la documentación oficial](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries).

Comment: Duda, para decir que usas Eloquent deberías invocar el nombre del modelo, por que al acceder a DB accedes pero al query builder que es distinto

Comment: Cierto, ya edito la respuesta.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda! :) Lo que no entiendo es que ahora me muestra el error de syntax error, unexpected '',NombreCliente), 2) ) ) INICI' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) espero que el cambiar las comillas simples por dobles lo solucione.Gracias!

Comment: De nada, si es que la respuesta te ayudó, márcala como correcta para ayudar a otros que tengan un problema similar

Comment: Para solucionar el problema agrege db::raw y quedo de la siguiente manera:

Comment: Listo, respuesta editada con `selectRaw`

Answer (score 0):

Solucion:

```
$result = DB::table('cliente')
      ->select(DB::raw("CONCAT( TRIM(SUBSTRING( NombreCliente,1,1) ), TRIM(SUBSTRING( NombreCliente, locate( ' ',NombreCliente), 2) ) ) AS INICIALES"))
      ->get();
```